# gphoto2 hook scripts - a guide?

Tags: scripting, images, hook

I posted this on raspberrypi.stackexchange but was directed here. I'm new to Linux / Unix, and I'm trying to get a tether / display script going with `gphoto2`.

```
gphoto2 --capture-tethered --hook-script=myhookscript.sh \
    --filename="/home/media/usbpendrive/image-%Y%m%d-%H%M%S.jpg" \
    --force-overwrite
```

This is supposed to download the image to my USB pen drive and then look for new commands in the hookscript.

The next stage would be to use `qiv` or similar image viewer to look for the last capture in the folder, then display it full screen. I would like someone to explain in simple terms how to make this hook script.

Comment: what's the contents of your script?

Comment: My script would only be what the example script is (http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/gphoto/index.php?title=Hook_scripts) I really don't know what everything means..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gphoto passes `$ACTION` and `$ARGUMENT` to the hook script, which you can use.

As an example:-

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $ARGUMENT ]; then
    if [[ $ARGUMENT =~ .+\.[jpg|JPG] ]]
    then
    # Then next few lines are optional
    # Alternatively pass $ARGUMENT directly to your image viewer eg:-
    # /usr/bin/shotwell "$ARGUMENT" &
    DIRNAME=$(dirname "$ARGUMENT")
    BASENAME=$(basename "$ARGUMENT")
    NEWFILENAME="$DIRNAME/my_new_folder/$BASENAME"
    mv "$ARGUMENT" "$NEWFILENAME"
            /usr/bin/shotwell "$NEWFILENAME" &
    fi
fi
```

This opens the file in `shotwell`, but that's easy to change to your preferred viewer.

The second `if` statement makes sure that shotwell is only used if the downloaded file is a JPG as I sometimes had the camera set to create raw (CR2 on a Canon) which wouldn't open in shotwell.  I suppose it could be expanded to to open those with another viewer.

The image will be saved as the argument supplied to `--filename` - in your case `/home/media/usbpendrive/image-20140616-125500.jpg`. That will be the value stored in `$ARGUMENT` and passed to your hook script.

You could use `dirname` and `basename` to split this path and filename to their relevant parts and then re-use them to create a new path and filename for the image.

```
$dirname /home/media/usbpendrive/image-20140616-125500.jpg
/home/media/usbpendrive 
$basename /home/media/usbpendrive/image-20140616-125500.jpg
image-20140616-125500.jpg
```

`$ARGUMENT` is only available when `gphoto` is downloading the image, so a check of `$ACTION` would be redundant in this case.

The file will need to have it's executable bit set, of course.

I only stopped using this when I found [Entangle](http://entangle-photo.org/) but I'm not sure that's available on the Pi.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; I will try it later on. Entangle is available for the RPI through a Jessie upgrade, but there are a few bugs in it and I haven't quite got it running yet (or maybe it's just me), which is why I went back to the scripting side. 

How would I put argument in the code to save the images to a folder before they are displayed?

Comment: This has been incredibly helpful - thank you. I now want to put more `$ARGUMENT` in to further expand on what this currently does. `QIV` is my choice of image viewer, and coupled with `--fullscreen` I now have an image displayed. I just need to work out a `SLEEP 10` before I initialise a shuffled slideshow `--shuffle`

Comment: If you're after a 10 second delay before starting QIV then enter `sleep 10s` on a line by itself just before you call `qiv --fullscreen --shuffle`. Type `man sleep` for more info on the sleep command.